# RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400

Tags: git, github

When pushing project git github repository error shows

error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400 send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

git push -u main error throws

Comment: Can you run 'GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push' . Maybe verbose output will offer more clues